# How to warp dynamic routes in Nextjs and Redux

Tags: next.js, redux, react-redux

I am trying to warp my dynamic route with Redux provider but it's telling me that my component should be warp with Redux provider which I already did. I am using Next.js 13.5

My **layout.tsx** for dynamic route:

```
blog->
   [slug]->
      page.js
      layout.tsx


export default function DynamicLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <Providers>
    <>
      
   
        {children}
       
      
       
    </>
    </Providers>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap your root level layout.tsx file, not your page component

For this, add a file called redux-provider.tsx under your app folder

```
"use client";

import { PropsWithChildren } from "react";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "../store/store"; // your store definitions

export default function ReduxProvider({ children }: PropsWithChildren<any>) {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            {children}
        </Provider>
    );
}
```

Add a file called provider.tsx under your app folder

```
"use client";

import { PropsWithChildren } from "react";

import ReduxProvider from "./redux-provider";

export default function Providers({ children }: PropsWithChildren<any>) {
    return (
        <ReduxProvider>
            {children}
        </ReduxProvider>
    );
}
```

In your root level layout.tsx file, wrap children param with Providers

```
import React from "react";

import Providers from './provider';

export default function RootLayout({
   // Layouts must accept a children prop.
   // This will be populated with nested layouts or pages
   children,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body>
                <Providers>
                    {children}
                </Providers>
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}
```

Comment: not working still now it's telling me that the warp component with a provider which I already did

Comment: Read more on https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#using-context-providers